# In Google Sheet how can I get a query to start from the row that contain specific text

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Hi I'm trying to get a formula that will start the query from a dynamic range I need my query to start from the row that contains a specific text "Parts" here's one of the formula I tried but nothing seem to work.

"=QUERY(INDIRECT("'Ticket Query'!B"&MATCH("Parts",'Ticket Query'!B:B,0)&":K26","Select * where C is not null",0)

I need this formula to be B6:K26 if "Parts" is at row 6
or  B7:K26 if "Parts" is at row 7 so on and so forth
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you try:

```
=query(indirect("'Ticket Query'!B"&xmatch("Parts",'Ticket Query'!B:B)&":K26"),"where C is not null",0)
```